# MonoTouch NavigationController on SubView?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, navigationcontroller

Every example I can find shows me how to create a project where the main window is a NavigationController.
I don't want that because once the users navigate to a certain part of my app, I don't want them to be able to get back until a certain point.

For the life of me I cannot figure out how to make a NavigationController be a SubView of my main window.
Can anyone help with this at all?  I have tried creating a new .xib file and making a NavigationController out of that, but I must be doing something wrong because it constantly crashes with errors that I can't understand or (like right now) It loads the Navigation Bar, with no title and doesn't change the View that is on the screen.

Is there any tutorials anywhere for doing a NavigationController NOT as your main View?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have some sample code?

As there seems to be no reason why you should not be able to do something like this:

// in main view

public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();

```
MyViewController controller = new MyViewController();

this.View.AddSubview (controller.View);
```

}

And it is fine to have the MyViewController inherited from UINavigationViewController.

Hope this helps.